# Matlab:How from the matrix M, I can have the format S in a text file?

Tags: matlab, matrix, text-files

```
M=[2    5    6
   4    8    9
   11  55    4
   89   2   47]

S = {[2    5    6],[4    8    9],[11   55    4],[89    2    47]}
```

How from the matrix M, I can have the format S in a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving few shots here, whichever works for you!

### Shot #1

```
%// Form the cell array version of the input matrix, M
S = mat2cell(M,ones(1,size(M,1)),size(M,2))

%// Write to text file 
output_file = 'results.txt'
dlmwrite(output_file,S,' ');
```

Code run -

```
>> type results.txt

2 5 6
4 8 9
11 55 4
89 2 47
```

---

### Shot #2

If you would like to have an output that exactly resembles the cell array version, you can use a `fprintf` based solution -

```
%// S used in this code would come from the earlier codes
output_file = 'results.txt'

fid = fopen(output_file, 'w+');
fprintf(fid, '{')                          %// Write the starting curly bracket
for ii=1:numel(S)-1
    fprintf(fid, '[%s],',num2str(S{ii}));  %// Write all data except the final cell
end
fprintf(fid, '[%s]',num2str(S{end}));  %// Write the data for final cell, 
                                        %// as it does not need any comma after it
fprintf(fid, '}')                       %// Write the ending curly bracket
fclose(fid);
```

Code run -

```
>> type results.txt

{[2  5  6],[4  8  9],[11  55   4],[89   2  47]}
```

---

### Shot #3

If you are not too happy about the irregular spacings between the numerals inside the `square brackets`, you can directly use `M`, to replace `S` at the two lines that use `fprintf` with the data -

Inside the loop -

```
fprintf(fid, '[%d %d %d]',M(ii,1),M(ii,2),M(ii,3));
```

After the loop exits -

```
fprintf(fid, '[%d %d %d]',M(end,1),M(end,2),M(end,3));
```

Code run -

```
>> type results.txt

{[2 5 6][4 8 9][11 55 4][89 2 47]}
```

Comment: @Divakar: I want the result exactly in this form: {[2    5    6],[4    8    9],[11   55    4],[89    2    47]}

Comment: @bzak Use `S'`, i.e. the transpose of `S`.

Comment: @Divakar: with brackets and commas !

Comment: @bzak You mean `brackets and commas` in the text file? Could you show us how the text file should look like, when opened in a text editor?

Comment: @Divakar: {[2    5    6],[4    8    9],[11   55    4],[89    2    47]}

Comment: @Divakar: Thank you very much Divakar :). I need this format for another part of my program!

Answer (score 2):

One-liner using [`mat2str`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) for the basic work and [`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) or [`strrep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) for the fine tuning (thanks to @Divakar for reminding me about the latter function):

```
S = regexprep(['{' mat2str(M) '}' ], ';', '],[');
```

or

```
S = strrep(['{' mat2str(M) '}' ], ';', '],[');
```

Then, to write to file, use

```
dlmwrite('tmp.txt', S, '')
```

Comment: @Divakar I didn't remember about that function. Thanks! I have added that

Comment: @LuisMendo: your answer gives space between 8 and 9 for 89 (8 9), the same for 11 (1 1),55 (5 5) and 47 (4 7)!

Comment: @bzak ?? No, it doesn't. Do `clear all`, define `M` as in your example, and paste my code as is

Comment: @LuisMendo: clc;
clear all;

M=[2    5    6
   4    8    9
   11  55    4
   89   2   47];

S = strrep(['{' mat2str(M) '}' ], ';', '],[');

%// Write to text file 
output_file = 'results.txt';
dlmwrite(output_file,S,' ');

Comment: @bzak Watch `S`. No spaces there. The problem seems to be `dlmwrite`. Use `dlmwrite('tmp.txt',S,'')`. I've edited my answer with this last part